# Satellite Assemblies Ignored

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I understand that satellite assemblies are supported in .NET Core 3.

To test, I created a console application and added `welcome.resx` and `welcome.de.resx`. Both have a string resource called Greeting. The main method does this:

```
ResourceManager r = new ResourceManager("MyTest.welcome",
                             Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

string greeting = r.GetString("Greeting"); 

Console.WriteLine(greeting);
```

So far, so good. It prints my English-language greeting `Hello`.

I verified that the build process created a folder called `de` under the build output folder, which contains `MyTest.resources.dll`. When I expressly request the German resource file:

```
string greeting = r.GetString("Greeting", 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de"));
```

I still get the English "Greeting" resource.

What might I be missing or how can I trouble-shoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the small test project also had an application manifest. Deleting the manifest resolved the error.

When I added the manifest back in, the project continued to work as expected. Apparently, the project got into an odd state that was resolved by removing and re-adding the manifest.